# TFS 2015 CI - Build artifacts are not generating for Console application in the solution which has web, console and WCF projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, continuous-integration, console-application, tfs-2015

I am creating a continuous integration using TFS 2015 CI for a project solution which has combination of  Web project, WCF Project , class libraries and Console Applcation. The Project is structured as shown below

```
Project Solution
 Project 1 (Web UI Project)
 Project 2 (WCF Project)
 Project 3 (Console Application-Batch Scheduler)
 Project 4 ( Class library)
 Project 5 ( Class library)
 Project 6 ( Class library)
```

I have added the MSBuild task and included the following arguments ,

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

The Problem is , All the dlls and build files generated in the Build artifacts directory for Web , WCF and class libraries project but not for the console application project.

Am I missing anything in MS Build argument or Is there any project specific setup required to generate the exe and release files for the console application in build artifact directory.

NOTE: In the TFS CI, Build is partially succeeded due to some long name issues in the web project but builds successfully in the local solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you build a solution?

Comment: @k7s5a Yes, I can build it locally.

Comment: Not clear what's the Bath Scheduler Console Application. Just create a normal console application as the same structure as you. Could not reproduce your issue. When you build locally did the exe and release files for the console application  generated? Besides which build are you using， vNext or XAML build?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT  Bath Scheduler Console Application is just a simple console application which We are using for Scheduling the Batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go through your build artifacts directory with all folder and sub-folders.You may have not noticed it. There is not any project specific setup required to generate the exe and release files for the console application in build artifact directory.

> **Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory**
>
> The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before
>   being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent_work\1\a.
>
> A typical way to use this folder is to publish your build artifacts
>   with the Copy files and Publish build artifacts steps.

Just need to make sure you have published the artifacts to the server or a share folder. To narrow down this issue, you could also try to directly build the Console Application project to see if the `.exe` generated successfully. And create a new normal Console Application instead of Console Application-Batch Scheduler to narrow down if the issue is related to it.

Comment: I had to use the MSBuild task to build console application and VisualStudioBuild task to build the rest of the aplication. MSBuild task takes *.*Proj file to build the projects but VisualStudioBuild task takes only the *.*sln files to build the project. Due to some reason my console application was not referenced in the *.*sln project file.