# TFS 2018 Build Console Application doesn't get included in the build artifact

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

I am setting up **Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery** infrastructure, My solution contains web projects, dlls, and a Console Application.
My issue is that all of my projects get included in the build artifact except the console application 
This is the default MSBuild arguments i use

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not any project specific setup required to generate the `exe` and release files for the console application in build artifact directory.

However if you want to include the Console Application in the artifact, you just need to add a **Copy Files** step to copy the Console Application to the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`. Of course you need to firstly make sure you have built the Console Application project and the `.exe` file generated successfully.

> **Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory**
>
> The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before
>   being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent_work\1\a.
>
> A typical way to use this folder is to publish your build artifacts
>   with the [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) and Publish build artifacts steps.

Alternately you can build the Console Application separately with `MSBuild` task, and `VisualStudioBuild` task to build the rest of the aplications. Reference this similar thread : [TFS 2015 CI - Build artifacts are not generating for Console application in the solution which has web, console and WCF projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732208/tfs-2015-ci-build-artifacts-are-not-generating-for-console-application-in-the?rq=1)

---

**UPDATE:**

You can simply copy them to web site. Just try using [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) task to do that, you can also write your own script to do that.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. I can now copy the exe to the artifact but when i deploy the artifact to IIS using IIS Web deploy, my exe didn't copy

Comment: @yo2011 That's expected behavior, you can simply copy them to web site. Just try using [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) task to do that, you can also write your own script to do that.

Comment: but i was expecting that to be part of the IIS Deploy Task because this task deploy the artifact to the IIS Server, got it?

Comment: Also, what is the difference beween CopyFile task and Windows Machine File Copy