# How to build pipeline with one .NET desktop app and one Web App in one sln file in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

Im new to Azure Devops and I have existing app consisting of portal service(web app) and desktop app in .NET which is in one solution in visual studio. What is the best way to build/publish such structured solution?

When I select asp.net as step, it builds successfully and forms zip. But I dont think the .NET serilog app is added.

When I select .NET Desktop I get message at the end:

> ##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

I would like to publish to On prem IIS server. Below is

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Why do you have to also deploy the console application to the target server? Does your web app depends on the console project in some aspects? If not, there's no need to deploy these two project in same artifact.

Comment: Hi Azm, is there any update for your issue? Could you share some details about which point are you being blocked by now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to build pipeline with one .NET desktop app and one Web App in one
> sln file in Azure Devops

You can use asp.net template to create the build pipeline. Since it specifies `solution: '**/*.sln'` by default, the build task will build both projects.

1.To deploy Asp.net core project in IIS server, you can Publish Build Artifact of Web Project in build pipeline. And then use IIS Web App Manage task, IIS Web App Deploy tasks to deploy it.

2.As for the console project, as I know we don't have official recommended task to deploy desktop applications. Instead you can use [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy the xx.exe to where you want.

(This task requires you to contain the xx.exe in build artifact, so you can keep outputs of two projects in same build artifact or have two build artifacts published for your two projects in build pipeline.)

Comment: Thanks Lance. The solution was to create two artifacts. I heard .NET core supports building based on csproj in the solution which is not the case for older ASP net apps

Answer (score 1):

When you configure pipeline you can choose predefined template. For .NET Desktop app you should pick this one:

[image]

More details about this you will find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net?view=azure-devops&tabs=vsts)

It will create such YAML for you

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Now to have your desktop application easily available for deployment you need to [publish it as artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

And to build ASP.NET app (I assumed that this is you case) you need to use ASP/NET template, but actually you can use this one for both cases.

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

In terms of deployment it all depends where you want to deploy your app. But if you deploy to Azure App Service please check this [Deploy a Web Deploy package (ASP.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-a-web-deploy-package-aspnet)

You question is lack of details thus it it difficult to give you best suited answer. But I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello Krzysztof, thanks. I added some details. This is precisely what I tried, both .NET app and web app Tasks, It builds the web app fine but there is no artifact created for the desktop app. And Id like to use IIS server on-prem, are you able to select which zip you want to deploy in the same way as with Azure App service?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline? Replying to message without knowing what you actually did is extremly difficult. And of course you alway can select what zip you will deploy also for deploying it to IIS on prem.

Comment: I added the pipeline. I also tried to include task copyfiles based on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468925/tfs-2018-build-console-application-doesnt-get-included-in-the-build-artifact  The C# app is some report sending service with serilog and I guess its supposed to be deployed together with the web app which is done via msdeploy.exe

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Thanks for your contribution. It seems like your YAML files are targeting the ASP.net & Desktop app separately. My question is, is it possible to target both in the same pipeline.